# How to check if a string is in the correct input when entered?

Tags: java, exception, character, joptionpane

I have a problem where i'm using a joptionpane to get the postal code of a user. I'm trying to check if the format is in L#L#L#L where L is a letter and # is a number. I'm trying to provide error checks to see if the postal code is in that format. I keep getting out of bounds errors if i look for a string that doesn't exist i.e. string.charAt(5) but I don't know how to fix it.

this is the current code that i'm erroring at

```
String postalCode = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter customer(s) " + (count + 1) + " postal code");

if (Character.isLetter(postalCode.charAt(0)) && 
    Character.isDigit(postalCode.charAt(1)) && 
    Character.isLetter(postalCode.charAt(2)) && 
    Character.isDigit(postalCode.charAt(3)) && 
    Character.isLetter(postalCode.charAt(4)) && 
    Character.isDigit(postalCode.charAt(5))) {
} 
else {
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple solutions. One would be to first validate the size of the input:

```
String postalCode = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter customer(s) " + (count + 1) + " postal code");

if ((postalCode.length() == 7) && Character.isLetter(postalCode.charAt(0)) && Character.isDigit(postalCode.charAt(1)) && Character.isLetter(postalCode.charAt(2)) && Character.isDigit(postalCode.charAt(3)) && Character.isLetter(postalCode.charAt(4)) && Character.isDigit(postalCode.charAt(5))) {

} else {
}
```

Another would be to use a regular expression:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
...
String postalCode = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter customer(s) " + (count + 1) + " postal code");
if (Pattern.matches("^[a-zA-Z]\\d[a-zA-Z]\\d[a-zA-Z]\\d[a-zA-Z]$", postalCode)) {

} else {
}
```

Edit: See deanosaur's comment below for a more concise regex.

Comment: That regex will match strings like `a1b2c3d4` and `1a1b2c3d4`, so its not strictly the same as the code above it. Try `^([a-zA-Z]\\d){3}[a-zA-Z]{1}$`

Comment: @deanosaur Good catch, thanks! I edited to add anchors.